# Prisma create custom function in schema

Tags: typescript, django-models, prisma, plumatic-schema

I have a mongo collection where there is a field called amount. What I want is whenever I ask for the amount I want it divided by 100.
The Django equivalent of it is a custom function inside the model.
I have done the same like this

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    
    def get_price(self):
        return self.price // 100
```

What is the prisma equivalent of this in typescript?

I tried the same thing in django and it worked fine. What I want is how to implement it in Prisma setup in nestJs.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    
    def get_price(self):
        return self.price // 100
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/result) part of their documentation answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the prisma docs.
I have to use custom field to query results.

it can be used as

```js
const xprisma = prisma.$extends({
  result: {
    user: {
      fullName: {
        // the dependencies
        needs: { firstName: true, lastName: true },
        compute(user) {
          // the computation logic
          return `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

const user = await xprisma.user.findFirst()

// return the user's full name, such as "John Doe"
console.log(user.fullName)
```

Here is the link to the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/result).